# Mongodb Hive Handler - Mongo URI with collection name and replication set not working

Tags: mongodb, hive, mongodb-query, pymongo, hiveql

I am using hive-mongo handler.
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Hive-Usage

Using a table like following to dump data from hive to mongo

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
            col1 string,
            col2 string,

    ) STORED BY "com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler"
    TBLPROPERTIES ( "mongo.uri" = "mongodb://{MONGO_USERNAME}:{MONGO_PASSWORD}@{MONGO_HOST}/{MONGO_DBNAME}.{COL1}");
```

This works fine. But now, I have multiple servers and replica set. I am not able to create a mongo URI with replica set and table name both in it. Can someone please help :

Here is the new mongo URI I tried which doesn't work :

```
 TBLPROPERTIES ("mongo.uri" = "mongodb://{MONGO_USERNAME}:{MONGO_PASSWORD}@hostname1,hostname2,hostname3/{MONGO_DBNAME}.{COL1}?replicaSet=test_setName");
```

Can someone please tell me whats wrong with it or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We hit the same problem.  For now we are working around it by just putting in hostname1 but still specifying the replica set.